# The larger the commutator subgroup is, the "less abelian" the group is

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, derived-subgroup

On the page of commutator subgroup [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) says that "the larger the commutator subgroup is, the "less abelian" the group is."

I know that for every group $G$ and $ N\trianglelefteq G$ the quotient $G/N$ is Abelian if and only if $[G,G] \le N$.

But what does "the larger the commutator subgroup is, the "less abelian" the group is" mean?

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, then its commutator is trivial...

Comment: It's not meant to be a rigorous statement. The point is that $G/N$ is the largest abelian quotient of $G$. The larger $N$ is, the smaller this quotient is.

Comment: Both $Z(G)$ and $[G,G]$ provide a sort of fuzzy "measure" of "how abelian" a group is. But it's a very rough measure; there are other ways of [quantifying how non-abelian a group is](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125501/measures-of-non-abelian-ness/125502#125502). Probably what Mathmo123 says is, in terms of "how big can an abelian image of $G$ be".

Answer (score 1):

It's a somewhat vague comment, which nevertheless makes some sense.  Since the commutator is, as you noticed, the minimum you need to "mod out by" in order to get an abelian group, its size does indeed correspond to how far the group is from being abelian.

Comment: I'd rather just say that if the commutator is bigger, then the group is further from being abelian.  In some sense you have to work harder (make more identifications) to get an abelian quotient.  I don't necessarily see any correlation with the size of the quotient.

Comment: I just meant that the "size" of the abelianization seems to still be up in the air.  Besides, of course, size is purely relative and so somewhat meaningless.   I don't know about $N$ right now either.  That complicates things.

Comment: I guess the point is that, in terms of relative size, the ratio of the group to its abelianization is going to be the order of the commutator.

Comment: Yes it seems pretty accurate.